# Prove Using Complex Multiplication

Tags: complex-numbers

Show the folowing general arctangent identity using complex multiplication,

$\arctan\frac{1}{a-b} = \arctan\frac{1}{a} + \arctan\frac{b}{a^2-ab+1}$,

for distinct real numbers $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Do you know an identity for $\tan(x+y)$? and do you see how it might come in handy?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $(a+i)(a^2-ab+1+ib) = (a^2+1)(a-b+i)$

---

More details: if $x > 0$, then $\arg(x+iy) = \arctan \dfrac{y}{x}$, with a similar expression for $x < 0$.

Looking at the right hand side makes it tempting to view it as $\arg(a+i)+\arg(a^2-ab+1+ib)$ and then it's just a matter of multiplying things together and simplifying.

Comment: And how does one stumble upon that identity?

Comment: @GerryMyerson stumbling clearly enough now?